# Watch window timeout when using ReaderWriterSlimLock in properties

Tags: c#, properties, locking, deadlock, watch

Why does the Visual Studio Watch window display 'Evaluation timed out' for any property that enters a ReaderWriterSlimLock?

To reproduce the problem, run the following program, pause it and enter Form1.form.Prop in the Watch window.

In a real-world application, once 'Evaluation timed out' appeared in the Watch window, other code cannot enter the lock anymore.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LockTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ReaderWriterLockSlim readerWriterLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.NoRecursion);

        private static Form1 form;

        public int Prop
        {
            get
            {
                readerWriterLock.EnterReadLock();
                readerWriterLock.ExitReadLock();

                return 1;
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            form = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. There is no problem if you put a breakpoint in an instance method of the form and access the property directly, only when accessing it via the static `form` variable when pausing the app without a breakpoint. The managed thread IDs are the same......

Comment: @user1892538 simply click the debugger's pause button. it will stop at in `Main` at `Application.Run(new Form1());`. When you then try to access `Form1.form.Prop` (via the static field!) the error occurs.

Comment: @user1892538 don't use a breakpoint, just start the application with debugger, and while the window is showing, click the pause button of the debugger. it will show that green arrow next to `Application.Run` to indicate that the code currently executing is "inside". At this point `Form1_Load` has already been executed and `form` is set to the instance of the open window.

Comment: As Rene said, it is essential to pause the application using the pause button in Visual Studio. The problem does not occur when a breakpoint is used. It seems illogical that it matters how the application is paused, but it makes a difference.

Comment: @user1892538 when I set this option I get a different error message "Expression could not be evaluated because a system frame is on top of the call stack" (I use a German IDE, so my translation is surely wrong). And again, we never "step into", we just "pause". When I "step into" I can see the value, too.

Comment: This is lossage in the VS2015 debugger, it is very buggy.  Whenever the debugger acts strange, always get a second opinion with Tools > Options > Debugging > General > "Use Managed Compatibility Mode" checkbox.  You now get a much better diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it is because the thread can ***not*** acquire this lock while it is invoking **unmanaged** code, that's what happens if you just click the debugger's pause button.

The *synchronization* mechanism will be *pending* till the thread reenters the *managed* environment. So, that would explain the timeout of `EnterReadLock` when you hit a pause - not followed by an `F10`.